# System.Configuration Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, winforms, configurationmanager, system.configuration

I am using System.Configuration in my assembly,
but as soon as I implement the getter/setters
the System.Configuration link on top of the code
gets greyed out (for not used in the assembly)

Configuration & the ConfigurationManager get underlined
red instead of teal color. Error message is :

> The type and/or namespace name Configuration could not
> be found. (Are you missing... etc.)

Strange thing is, in my test program the same code
runs without errors. Is there anything I need to
change in the properties or the assembly itself to
get System.Configuration running?

Thank you for your help!

```
public string getAppSetting(string key)
    {
        //Load AppSettings
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
                                OpenExeConfiguration(
                                System.Reflection.Assembly.
                                GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        //Zurückgeben der dem Key zugehörigen Value
        return config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
    }

    public void setAppSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        //Save AppSettings
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
                                OpenExeConfiguration(
                                System.Reflection.Assembly.
                                GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        //Überprüfen ob Key existiert
        if (config.AppSettings.Settings[key] != null)
        {
            //Key existiert. Löschen des Keys zum "überschreiben"
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
        }
        //Anlegen eines neuen KeyValue-Paars
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
        //Speichern der aktualisierten AppSettings
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the System.Configuration link"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly.

Comment: Thank You so much... i am just a beginning... somehow magically i must have added the reference before and forgot about it...

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer *you* liked best when allowed to (after 15 minutes after your question was asked). Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add reference of `System.Configuration` from your application as shown below :-

Right click on References --> Add Reference.

Select `System.Configuration` and it will add the required reference!

Comment: Thank You so much... i am just a beginning... somehow magically i must have added the reference before and forgot about it...